# False claim for solution of $\Delta u = \frac{1}{2}$ using Brownian motion?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I've seen the following claim:

> Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded, open set with smooth boundary and $u$ a smooth solution of the Dirichlet-problem
>           $$ \begin{cases}
>   \frac{1}{2} \Delta u = 1 \ on \ U \\
>   u = 0 \ on \ \partial U
>   \end{cases}.$$
>           For $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ define the stopping time
>           $ \tau(y) := \inf \{ t \in \mathbb{R} | B_t(y) \in \partial U  \} $
>           where we use the filtration generated by the $n$-dimensional Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$. Then for all $x \in \overline{U}$
>           $$ u(x) = E^x(\tau). $$

But for example in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123980/on-hitting-time-of-brownian-motion-and-itos-lemma?noredirect=1&lq=1) it is claimed, that $E^x(\tau)=\infty$. Is the above claim false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tau$ in this question and in your linked question are different. In the linked question $\tau$ is the hitting time of the boundary of the set $(-\infty,1)$. Here you take $\tau$ to be the hitting time of the boundary of a bounded set (so that in particular, $U \neq (- \infty, 1)$).

With $\tau$ defined as in this question, you have that for $0<p<\infty$, $\sup_{x \in U} E_x[\tau^p] < \infty$. To prove this, first note that 
$$P_x(\tau < 1) \geq P_x(|B_1 - x| > \operatorname{diam}(U)) =: p_0 > 0$$
Now let $q = 1- p_0 < 1$ so that $\sup_{x \in U}P_x(\tau \geq 1) \leq q$.

Then by the strong Markov property we have that 
$$P(\tau \geq k) \leq (2\pi)^{-n/2} \int_U \exp(-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2}) P_y(\tau \geq k-1) dy$$
so that inductively we get that $P(\tau \geq k) \leq q^k$. Finally, to conclude, note that
$$E_x[\tau^p] = \int_0^\infty P_x[\tau^p \geq t] dt = \int_0^\infty ps^{p-1} P_x[\tau \geq s] ds \leq 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty p (k+1)^{p-1}q^k < \infty$$
and take the $\sup$ over $x \in U$.