# How to detect if a moving point has passed through the connecting line between two other fixed points?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a moving point (Tag) and two fixed points (anchors). I have the distance from the anchors to tag at each time. I also have the position of the anchors and the last position of the tag. I calculate the intersections of two circles with center of the anchors and radii of the distance from each anchor to each tag. I have two possible positions for the tag at each time. How can I determine if the tag has passed through the connecting line between the anchors using all the known information?
Thanks for your help in advance
I would willingly provide more information if necessary.

Comment: I guess the tag moves continuosly (if not It Is impossible to do any kind of prediction). Is the tag forced to stay in a plane or it can be anywhere in the three dimensionale space (in the latter case i think the probability of passing throught the line will be zero at any given time)?

Comment: Is this a 2D question? Everything in the same plane?

Comment: it can move continuously. it may also stop for some time in a position. like a warehouse robot. it is in the 2d dimension. everything is in the same 2d plane.

Comment: In two dimensions, this is a reasonable problem to solve most of the time. There can be some doubt in the case where the Tag passes extremely close to one of the anchors; did the Tag pass the anchor on the side facing the other anchor, or on the opposite side? Another problematic case is if the Tag moves to a point exactly on the line segment between the anchors. Looking at the position of the Tag on the line and the position before, the Tag has not yet passed through the line. If the Tag later moves off the line, you can't tell at that time which side of the line it came from originally.

Comment: So with the given data, if the Tag moves exactly onto the line and then moves in the same direction, there is no step at which you know that the Tag crossed the line rather than bouncing off it. One more bit of information, remembering which side the Tag came from in the case where it is exactly on the line, would resolve this.

Comment: Does the tag only move in a straight line between successive intervals? If not, there is a problem that  even though a straight line between 2 successive steps intersects the line connecting the anchors, the tag might have followed a curved path around one of the anchors.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. the tag will not be necessarily observed exactly on the line. at one frame we have the tag position determined and at the next frame we have two possible solutions which are actually the two intersections of the circles I explained. regardless if the tag stays on the same side of the connecting line or passes through the line, there is always two intersections (assuming anchors are that near that we have two intersections), at each side of the line. my problem is I can not determine if the tag has passed the line or is still on the same side.

Comment: I can assume that it always moves in a straight line although it may not. but even in this case, I can not determine if it has passed the connecting line.

Comment: Thanks Macro for your answer. It makes sense. Is there any other kind of information that if we know, we may be able to check this? or if we add more constraints?

Comment: well, Macro deleted his comment but he said it is impossible to determine this with the information that we have and it seems to be the case and correct.

Comment: @Shayan, sorry about that. I deleted the comments because i wanted to give the proof of what i had said in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to know for sure if the Tag has crossed the line between the two anchors. Indeed let define a coordinate system such that the line connecting the two anchors is the $x$ axys and the two anchors have coordinates $A_1=(x_1,0),A_2=(x_2,0)$ with $0=x_1< x_2$. Let suppose now that at a given time the two distances are $d_1,d_2$. The circonferences of radii $d_1,d_2$ and center $A_1,A_2$ have equations
$$
x^2+y^2=d_1^2
$$
$$
(x-x_2)^2+y^2=d_2^2
$$
By solving the system you obtain $x_\text{int}=\frac{d_1^2-d_2^2+x_2^2}{2x_2}$ and $y_\text{int}=\pm \sqrt{d_1^2-x_\text{int}^2}$.

So, unless $d_1^2=x_\text{int}^2$ (that happens with probability $0$) we have that the two intersections are always one above and one below the line.

From a probabilistic point of view the Tag will cross the line in a finite amount of time.

W.l.o.g. we assume that at the time $t=0$ the Tag is in the negative semiplane (this is equivalent to fix the verse of the $y$-axys), i.e. if we call $T_t$ the position of the tag, at the instant $t=0$ we have $T_0:=(T_x,T_y)$ with $T_y<0$.

If we assume that the Tag moves continuosly in the time we can assume the  process $T_t$ to be a $2$-dimensional Wiener process (see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#Relation_to_Wiener_process)) i.e. $T_t= (T_x,T_y) + (B^x_t,B^y_t)$ where $B^x_t,B^y_t$ are 1-dimensional independent Brownian motions.

The problem is now equivalent to find the first hitting time
$$
\tau:= \inf\{t >0 : T_y+ B^y_t \ge 0\}=\inf\{t >0 :  B^y_t \ge |T_y|\}
$$
It is known that $\tau < \infty$ a.s., but as shown in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23286/a-question-regarding-the-hitting-time-formula-in-brownian-motion/23291#23291) answer its expectation is infinite. In the linked answer it is also shown that the PDF of the hitting time is given by
$$
f_\tau (t)=\frac{|T_y|}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}t^{ - 3/2} e^{ - |T_y|^2 /(2t)} ,\;\; t > 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The anchors define a line and a segment and the current position of the tag and its previous position define another line and segment. Use standard techniques to find the equations of a line given the coordinates of two points on the line. Equate the formula for the first line to the second and solve and if there is a real solution the lines intersect. What we really need to know is if the segments intersect.

Let $A_1(x,y)$ and $A_2(x,y)$ be the coordinates of the endpoints of the 1st segment and $B_1(x,y)$ and $B_2(x,y)$ be the coordinates of the endpoints of the 2nd segment.
Let (X,Y) be the coordinates of the intersections of the lines (if there is a real solution).

If
$A_1(x) \leq X \leq A_2(x) \ $ and
$\ A_1(y) \leq Y \leq A_2(y) \ $ and
$\ B_1(x) \leq X \leq B_2(x) \ $ and
$\ B_1(y) \leq Y \leq B_2(y)$  then the segments intersect and the tag has passed between (or is on) the line connecting the anchors.

Edit: Following a clarification by the OP. the tag effectively also has a reflected position at any given time that is reflected across the anchor line. A segment connecting the two reflected positions of the tag also intersects the anchor line if the non reflected tags intersect the line. However, a segment connecting a non reflected tag position and reflected tag position will not necessarily have an intersection with the anchor segment. Taking into account that we do not know if we have a reflected position or not, it is impossible to determine if the tag has crossed the anchor segment, without further information such as a third vector to the tag or the current speed of the tag.

Comment: thanks, but there are actually two possible current positions. and they are each at opposite sides of the line. considering one of the possible points, there is always an intersection and considering the other, there is never an intersection.

Comment: thanks. I agree with the final conclusion.